# Accessing data from list C# that stores deserialized XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

**this is my Xml file that I am trying to desirialize:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AddressDirectory>
  <Address>
    <HouseNo>1</HouseNo>
    <StreetName>Pitampura</StreetName>
    <City>Delhi</City>
  </Address>
  <Address>
    <HouseNo>4</HouseNo>
    <StreetName>Rohini</StreetName>
    <City>Delhi</City>
  </Address>
</AddressDirectory>
```

**these are my classes:**

```
public class AddressDirectory
{
    [XmlElement("Address")] 
    public List<Address> addressList = new List<Address>(); 
}
public class Address
{
    public int HouseNo { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

**this is my main:**

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AddressDirectory));
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\myXml.xml");
object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
AddressDirectory XmlData = (AddressDirectory)obj;
reader.Close();
```

**this is how I access the elements that must have ben saved in the list:**

```
XmlData.addressList[0].HouseNo;
XmlData.addressList[0].StreetName; 
XmlData.addressList[0].City;
```

**or in a loop I access like this:**

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("house number for {0}: ", i);
                Console.WriteLine(XmlData.addressList[i].HouseNo);
                Console.Write("Street Name  for {0}: ", i);
                Console.WriteLine(XmlData.addressList[i].StreetName);
                Console.Write("City         for {0}: ", i);
                Console.WriteLine(XmlData.addressList[i].City);
            }
```

**this is the error that I am getting when I execute the program:**

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

I guess this is because we are not adding anything in the list. Because to add to the list we have to use List.Add() somewhere in the main.

**this is my main() after editing:**

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AddressDirectory));
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\addressDirectory.xml");
            object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            AddressDirectory XmlData = (AddressDirectory)obj;
            reader.Close();


            for (int i = 0; i < XmlData.addressList.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Information for item #{0}", i + 1);
                Console.WriteLine(" - House Number ... {0}", XmlData.addressList[i].HouseNo);
                Console.WriteLine(" - Street Name .... {0}", XmlData.addressList[i].StreetName);
                Console.WriteLine(" - City ........... {0}", XmlData.addressList[i].City);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

now it does not  give any error and neither does it display the contents of the List

Comment: You should probably use the addressList bounds for your `for` condition: `for (int i = 0; i < XmlData.addressList.Length; i++)`

Comment: for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) - You havn't got 10 items so u Cant access to XmlData.addressList[9] because it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `XmlData.addressList.Count` property for your for condition:

```
for (int i = 0; i < XmlData.addressList.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Information for item #{0}", i + 1);
    Console.WriteLine(" - House Number ... {0}", XmlData.addressList[i].HouseNo);
    Console.WriteLine(" - Street Name .... {0}", XmlData.addressList[i].StreetName);
    Console.WriteLine(" - City ........... {0}\n", XmlData.addressList[i].City);
}
```

Here's another way to do it, along with the rest of the code I used to test it (which worked with your xml file and classes):

```
public static void Main()
{        
    var addresses = new List<Address>();
    var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AddressDirectory));
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Rufus\Documents\temp\temp.xml"))
    {
        addresses.AddRange(
            ((AddressDirectory)deserializer.Deserialize(reader)).addressList);
    }

    int counter = 1;
    foreach (var address in addresses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Information for item #{0}", counter++);
        Console.WriteLine(" - House Number ... {0}", address.HouseNo);
        Console.WriteLine(" - Street Name .... {0}", address.StreetName);
        Console.WriteLine(" - City ........... {0}\n", address.City);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.List<XmlDeserializer.AddressDetails>' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<XmlDeserializer.AddressDetails>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\ahsan\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\XmlDeserializer\XmlDeserializer\Program.cs 64 53 XmlDeserializer

Comment: didnt give any error but didn't display anything either(maybe the List is not popullating). Am I deserializing it right? coz normally when we add anything to a List we have to use something like List.Add([parameter]) but in the code I showed above I am not using Add() anywhere.

Comment: Your exact code works for me with the change I made in the sample above - it writes out two records.

Comment: I added the code I used for testing. It works fine with your xml and classes.

Comment: sorry by mistake i deleted the last comment i was trying to edit. thanks for your help i really appriciate it. i will try to make a new project and then try may be some random problem is occuring in displaying the contents of the list

Comment: i have added my code in Main(). have a look, see if anything I am doing wrong